# How to use wp theme and author uri

Tags: wordpress, themes, uri

In WordPress CSS file Author and Theme URI is already present.

```
Theme Name: myTheme
Theme URL: https://themestore.com/themename
Description: myTheme
Author: Author
Author URI: https://author.com
Version: 1.0.0
```

How to call these into a link on any page of the WP blog...

If I would like to put link on WP pages for author from CSS file and the theme link from CSS file...

Comment: In case anyone who copies the format of this question experiences trouble, be sure to change the `Theme URL:` annotation to `Theme URI:` as per [the official WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Wordpress function to get theme NAME and URI from style.css comments.
Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_theme/

Code Snippet:

```
$theme_data = wp_get_theme();
echo $theme_data->get( 'Name' );
echo $theme_data->get( 'ThemeURI' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$theme_wp = wp_get_theme();
echo $theme_wp->get( 'Name' );
echo $theme_wp->get( 'AuthorURI' );
```

Echo the name of an installed theme:

```
$theme_wp = wp_get_theme( 'twentynineteen' );
if ( $theme_wp->exists() )
    echo esc_html( $theme_wp );
```